# Is it possible to base an if-statement on a constructor?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In my code I have 3 different constructors, one requiring two doubles, and one requiring 3 doubles, and one that requires nothing.

I also have a function that overloads my << so that it can print them out, but only one of them at the time.

```
OnePoint a(3.2, 3.2, 3.2); 
    OnePoint b(3.1, 3.1); 

    cout << a << endl; 
    cout << b << endl;
```

Is there a way I can I can write:

If(Constructor with 2 parameters is called){

(then do this)

}else{Do this}

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #include <vector>

    class OnePoint {
    private:
        double xvalue;
        double yvalue;
        double zvalue; 

    public:
        OnePoint(double x, double y) {
            xvalue = x;
            yvalue = y;
        }
        OnePoint(double x, double y, double z) {
            xvalue = x;
            yvalue = y;
            zvalue = z; 
        }
        OnePoint() {

        }

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& printh, OnePoint& cPoint) {
            if () { //Here
                printh << "(" << cPoint.xvalue << ',' << cPoint.yvalue << ")";

            }
            else {
                printh << "(" << cPoint.xvalue << ',' << cPoint.yvalue << "," << cPoint.zvalue << ")";
            }
            return printh;

        }

    };
```

Comment: Why not give all 3 data members sensible values in both constructors? Otherwise you will have to if-else all the client code.

Comment: You have a design problem here.  Having a 'point' class with an uninitialized 'z' value is a bad idea.  What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: It's actually a part of a bigger program. I just didn't add the rest as it would be irrelevant in this situation. It's a class onepoint, class line and class polygon. Add two points, get a line, add lines+onepoint,lines+lines, and so on to get a polygon, and polygon + polygon = polygon. It's something I have been working on for several days as a beginner programmer, but it requires one last thing and that is points with two coordinates, and with 3 coordinates. So 2d and 3d points.

Comment: My polygon class is a constists of vectors of Points, and that is why the #include <vector> is there.

Comment: The programs works super nice with only 2 coordinates. The absolutely last part is 3 coordinates.

Comment: XY problem. You're trying to use 2d and 3d points in your application but you're trying to get an answer to using "if-statements on a constructor". Do you really have to merge 2d and 3d points into the same class? Is there any reason why you don't have separate classes for 2d and 3d points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example reflects a strange design choice.  It's as if you want the same class to represent two kinds of points.  Your current design has the ugly problem of "What happens if I try to add a 2d point to a 3d point?"

There are pretty much two elegant answers here, either have the print behavior not print `0` value-d Z coordinates (meaning all points are 3d, but 2d points can fake it), or use two distinct classes.  The former allows you to add 2d and 3d points together, the latter disallows it.  Both are better than your current situation where it's allowed but will break things.

I suggest the former, **just use an if-statement that detects 0'd z-values**.

It's possible your scenario involves something more sophisticated, like polymorphism, but it's unlikely.

Also, most programmers would just print `(x, y, z)` for both 2d and 3d points (we are a lazy bunch).

Comment: I didn't think of that problem. Yes, I think I will go with x,y,z. Because my class line consists of two Points. My class Polygon also consists of a vector of points. So if I make a new class for 3D Points I need the other classes as well *2. I probably should have thought of this earlier, but hey, im a noob.

Comment: The question you really need to answer is "Do I want to be able to add 2d and 3d points together?"

The Polygon and Line classes can be generalized using templates so it isn't that big a problem to have 2 separate underlying classes, although I think it's easier to just have 1 point class in general.

Comment: Since when i "add" two points, they aren't really adding. They are just putting them beside each other so that Point a + Point b = Line c; (3.0,3.0)+(1.0,1.0) = (3.0,3.0)(1.0,1.0) with overloading the + operator. I don't think I need to be able to add 2D and 3D points, but If I could get rid of the z, I would be able to do so. I guess I would be able to do so anyway because this isn't really adding, but since I barely know templates - I'll stick to hiding the Z.

Answer (score 2):

Since you:

```
#include <vector>
```

Seems like you may want to just use it:

```
class OnePoint {
private:
    std::vector<double> values;

public:
    OnePoint() { }
    OnePoint(std::initializer_list<double> v) : values(v) { }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const OnePoint& cPoint) {
        os << '(';
        bool first = true;
        for (double v : cPoint.values) {
            if (!first) os << ", ";
            os << v;
            first = false;
        }
        return os << ')';
    }
};
```

Note that you should take the `OnePoint` by reference to *const* in `operator<<`, not just by reference.

This allows:

```
std::cout << OnePoint{} << std::endl;          // prints ()
std::cout << OnePoint{1.0, 2.0} << std::endl;  // prints (1, 2)
```

Answer (score -3):

How about just recording it?

```
#include <vector>

class OnePoint {
private:
    double xvalue;
    double yvalue;
    double zvalue;
    bool constructor_with_2_parameters_is_called;

public:
    OnePoint(double x, double y) {
        xvalue = x;
        yvalue = y;
        constructor_with_2_parameters_is_called = true;
    }
    OnePoint(double x, double y, double z) {
        xvalue = x;
        yvalue = y;
        zvalue = z;
        constructor_with_2_parameters_is_called = false;
    }
    OnePoint() {
        constructor_with_2_parameters_is_called = false;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& printh, OnePoint& cPoint) {
        if (constructor_with_2_parameters_is_called) {
            printh << "(" << cPoint.xvalue << ',' << cPoint.yvalue << ")";

        }
        else {
            printh << "(" << cPoint.xvalue << ',' << cPoint.yvalue << "," << cPoint.zvalue << ")";
        }
        return printh;

    }

};
```

Comment: @DavidLund That is a terrible solution, because you will have to use if-elses each time you're thinking of reading from the `z` data member. You really should not have to switch your code depending on how an object was built. You have a serious design problem.

Comment: mhm, so what would you propose? except for putting default 0

Comment: @DavidLund Write your class so that it doesn't matter how you initialized it.